# How to determine whether a given graph is planar or not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

We are given a graph $G$:

[image: Graph G]

After struggling for hours, I think it may be planar. If it is, I couldn't realize how to determine a proper drawing.

Things I've tried:

- Finding a subgraph isomorphic or homeomorphic to $K_5$ or $K_{33}$ (Since $K_{33}$ has no odd cycles I've tried removing them).
- Noted it has $8$ cycles of length $3$, $K_5$ has $10$. Maybe there is a way of obtaining the others that I'm not aware of).
- Obtaining a subgraph (with $|V|\geq3$) that has no cycles of length $3$ and $|E| > 2|V|-4$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: It looks suspiciously like someone started with a planar embedding of a graph and then moved a few vertices to make lots of edges intersect. Have you tried moving the vertices around to recover the planar picture? What if you just move $h$ and $b$ down to the bottom?

Comment: @Karl Well, It's part of kabenyuk's solution now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question's been solved, but I couldn't help but post this more symmetric planar embedding

[image]

Comment: Was about to post this too. It's an antiprism graph: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AntiprismGraph.html